# Why do pandas and numpy take so much time to install during deployment of an app in IBM CloudFoundry?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ibm-cloud

I hva been trying to deploy apps in IBM CloudFoundry and I have been successful only once. When I deleted that app and tried to deploy a new one with almost same code except a few minor changes here and there, I get an error like this:

```
Error staging application churnwebappv3: timed out after 15 minute(s)
FAILED

Finished: FAILED
```

I'm sure there is nothing wrong with my code as the very same app had got deployed a few days back, except the front-end was a bit different. I even made sure I had enough space allotted to my app so I deleted all my previous apps and allocated 256M to my app-to-be-deployed but I still receive a time-out error.

One thing I noticed is that bumpy and pandas take up a major chunk of the time during installation and the only time they didn't take that long was the time when my app had got deployed. This is how my error logs look towards the end. As you can see, numpy and pandas take so much time to install. Is this normal or am I missing something?

```
          .
          .
          .
          Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3.0,>=2.18->ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0->ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
          Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3.0,>=2.18->ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0->ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/2b/26e37a4b034800c960a00c4e1b3d9ca5d7014e983e6e729e33ea2f36426c/certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157kB)
          Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0,>=2.18->ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0->ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e3/afebe61c546d18fb1709a61bee788254b40e736cff7271c7de5de2dc4128/idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
          Installing collected packages: click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Flask, jmespath, docutils, urllib3, chardet, certifi, idna, requests, six, python-dateutil, ibm-cos-sdk-core, ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer, ibm-cos-sdk, numpy, pytz, pandas, scipy, joblib, scikit-learn, cycler, pyparsing, kiwisolver, matplotlib, imbalanced-learn
            WARNING: The script flask is installed in '/tmp/contents609270305/deps/0/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
            Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
            WARNING: The script chardetect is installed in '/tmp/contents609270305/deps/0/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
            Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
            Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-core: started
              Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-core: finished with status 'done'
            Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer: started
              Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer: finished with status 'done'
            Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk: started
              Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk: finished with status 'done'
            Running setup.py install for numpy: started
              Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
              Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
              Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
              Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
              Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
              Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'done'
            Running setup.py install for pandas: started
              Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
              Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
              Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
Error staging application churnwebappv3: timed out after 15 minute(s)
FAILED

Finished: FAILED
```

EDIT: I managed to deploy my app through the CLI terminal. The app started at the 14th minute, just before the 15 minutes timeout, with pandas taking up almost 10 minutes.

[This](https://github.com/sthitaprajna-mishra/finalchurnapp) is the link of my github repo. The previous tries which failed were carried out using IBM Toolchain resource. That is the only difference between the failed attempt and the successful one.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `numpy` requires installation of a C-compiler, e.g. `gcc`, which takes a *very* long time.

Comment: It looks like numpy is being installed from source (instead of a prebuilt wheel file). Installing from source cand take some time as @QuangHoang wrote. C and Fortran compilers are required.

Comment: @jakub Is there a way I can fasten the process? Also, pandas take up a lot more time than bumpy.

Comment: Share your manifest.yml, requirements.txt and how you deploy. Are you using the buildpack available in the Cloud Foundry environment?

Comment: @data_henrik https://github.com/sthitaprajna-mishra/finalchurnapp - this is the link of my git repo. Also, I managed to deploy my app through the CLI terminal. The app started at the 14th minute, just before the 15 minutes timeout, with pandas taking up almost 10 minutes.

Comment: Include everything into the questions. Repos change over time. Q&A should be usable for others, too